# Batch file to run 32bit application in 64bit Windows

Tags: batch-file, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to run an application from a batch file but I get an error due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows. 
Is there a way that I can run the application in 32bit mode using the batch file? 
Thanks and cheers.

Comment: Weird; 64-bit systems shouldn't have a problem with 32-bit programs (just 16-bit programs).

Comment: show your batch code and what error do you get

Comment: Well I am sorry that I just found out the application is actually a 16-bit application. I just have "APPLICATION_NAME <input.txt>output.txt" in a .bat file and this was working in 32-bit Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As SomethingDark posted, there should be no problems running a 32-bit application on an x64 system. But sometimes the error doesn't come from the OS but from the application itself. Some programs just refuse to work on anything but an x86 OS. As far as I know, there is only one way to force them to work: the compatibility mode which simulates WinXP 32.

You could try to add `set __COMPAT_LAYER=WinXP` just before calling your 32-bit program. This might help.